# How strict should one be when defining guards for function clauses?

Tags: elixir

How strict should I be when I define my function clauses?

Elixir allows writing function heads in a range from *no guards* over *check types* up to *verify value within range*.

So for example I don't know what style to use in a function like this:

```
def measure(args = %{times: times, path: path}) do ...

def measure(args = %{times: times, path: path}) when is_integer(times) and is_binary(path) do ...

def measure(args = %{times: times, path: path}) when is_integer(times) and times > 0 and is_binary(path) ...
```

The is of course a problem when checking to many conditions: the line gets too long, and having an extra line for the guards doesn't seem like a good idea to me. It makes it harder to distinguish between actual code and function headers...

What would you recommend for the *strictness* of my function definitions?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Vote to close.

Comment: I know that there is no definite answer to this question, but I was hoping someone maybe knows a good article or similar regarding this topic. Will mark as resolved.

Comment: "there is no definite answer to this question" - - may I humbly suggest you read the site's FAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using guards is completely ok for checking data for contentual causes. But trying to ensure type-safety might be better done with Dialyzer (https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir).

Even using no guards at all will result in a matching error somewhere else. So if you need to ensure the data given to you is valid for your algorithms, guard it as early as possible.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I was aware of Dialyzer, but it's good to know there is a wrapper for using it with elixir.